# Application Defined or object-defined error 3

Tags: vba, excel, range

I am trying to take specific data from **`"sheet1"`** and put it in another sheet in specific places (specifically financial data).

In this code I am trying to create a range that will only include data from the part of financial data going from current assets to total current assets (or total assets if there are no non current assets).

Its thrown Error on the **`"Set range1"`** lines.

I am trying to create a range from the current asset sell to the total asset cell to use later in the code.

```
lastCol = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a1").End(xlToRight).Column
lastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(65536, lastCol).End(xlUp).Row
Set crntassone = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a1", Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Find("Current Assets:")

 If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a1", Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Find("Total Current Assets") Is Nothing Then
     Set ttlass = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a1", Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Find("Total Assets")
     Set range1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(crntassone, ttlass)
 Else
     Set crntasstwo = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a1", ActiveSheet.Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Find("Total Current Assets")
     Set range1 = Range(crntassone, crntasstwo)
 End If
```

Comment: Are you sure `crntassone` is not `Nothing`? If it is, the calls to `Range(crntassone, ...` will fail

Comment: Another issue: your calls to `Find`, whatever parameters you don't specify will use whatever was last used, either by code or the user.  Almost certainly not what you want.

Comment: @chrisneilsen It could be nothing... which means I should set up an if statement for if it is 'Nothing'. But I know that there is a cell in this sheet that contains the "Current Assets:" string, so it shouln't be 'Nothing'. Unless I am formatting my parameters in 'Find' incorrectly. Are you saying I should specify the optional parameters in my calls to Find, i.e. after, lookin, lookat, etc.?

Comment: Regarding Find, yes I am saying you should specify all optional parameters.  Unlike most other functions, unspecified Find parameters take their value from the last use of Find, either by the user or code.  You really have no idea what you will get if you don't specify.

Comment: Regarding `crntassone` and the possibility of `Nothing`, try putting a break on the `Set range1 = ` lines and check what ranges the two parameters point to in the Watch window.

Comment: Another point: `Set crntasstwo = ...` uses a mixture of  `Worksheets("Sheet1")` and `ActiveSheet`.  Not a good idea, use one or the other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my range for 'Find' wasn't actually spanning my whole sheet. Due to the formatting of my charts in excel, 'xlToRight' and 'xlUp' were not spanning the entirety of all the rows and columns that were being used (hard to explain in words). In addition to specifying certain extra parameters for 'Find', I also used 'SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)' to locate the last cell in my sheet. Here are the changes I made

```
Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

Dim LastColumn As Long
    LastColumn = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column

Set crntassone = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1", Cells(LastRow,  LastColumn)).Find(What:="Current assets:", After:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
 If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1", Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Find("Total Current Assets") Is Nothing Then
     Set ttlass = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1", Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Find("Total Assets")
     Set range1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(crntassone, ttlass)
```

Answer (score 0):

Range Object of Sheets wont take parameters as you have defined. You should write parameters like this

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range(cells(1,2),cells(3,4))
```

Note : 1,2,3,4 are just for eg. Figure out this values as i cant see your excel

Comment: Wrong on two counts: if `Sheet1` is not active this will error.  And `Range` _will_ take other ranges as parameters.

Comment: My sheet2 was active and i tried setting range of Sheet1, encountered no error. Below code works fine..Sheets(2).Activate 
 Set range1 = Sheets(3).Range("A:A")

Comment: @pranav012 unfortunately I do not know the specific numeric values of the cells because that will change from document to document. I am writing this for multiple documents and trying to automate it as much as possible, hence me using 'Find'. Also I tried using 'range.address' on both and seeing if it was because .range wouldnt accept other ranges but it still threw the same error, so I believe it will accept ranges as parameters.